How to consume Kafka messages from Logstash?
I'm playing a bit with the latest versions of Logstash and Kafka but I can't get the Kafka input to work.
Here a brief summary of my setup:

I'm using Docker Compose with apache/kafka:3.9.0 and logstash:8.16.1 Docker images.
The Kafka broker is reachable by Logstash, indeed, the Kafka output works as expected with the generator and http inputs.

This is my logstash.conf
input {
  generator {
    count => 10
    message => "Hello, World!"
  }
  http {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => 8080
    codec => json {
        target => "[data]"
    }
  }
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka:19092"
    codec => "json"
    topics => ["logstash-input"]
    group_id => "logstash_group"
    client_id => "logstash_consumer"
    auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka:19092"
    codec => "json"
    topic_id => "logstash-output"
  }
}

and this is the docker-compose.yaml:
services:
  kafka:
    image: "apache/kafka:3.9.0"
    hostname: "kafka"
    container_name: "kafka"
    restart: "always"
    labels:
      docker-hub: "https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/kafka"
      github: "https://github.com/apache/kafka"
      readme: "https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/docker/examples/README.md#using-environment-variables"
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: "broker,controller"
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: "/var/lib/kafka/data"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "${KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP:-EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT}"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "${KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS:-EXTERNAL://localhost:9092,INTERNAL://kafka:19092}"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: "${KAFKA_LISTENERS:-EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,INTERNAL://kafka:19092,CONTROLLER://kafka:29092}"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "${KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME:-INTERNAL}"
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: "${KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES:-CONTROLLER}"
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: "${KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS:-1@kafka:29092}"
    networks:
      - logstash-network
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - kafka-secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets
      - kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
      - kafka-config:/mnt/shared/config

  logstash:
    image: "logstash:8.16.1"
    hostname: "logstash"
    container_name: "logstash"
    restart: "always"
    labels:
      docker-hub: "https://hub.docker.com/_/logstash"
      github: "https://github.com/elastic/logstash"
      readme: "https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/docker-config.html"
    environment:
      LOGSTASH_LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
      MONITORING_ENABLED: "${MONITORING_ENABLED:-false}"
      XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED: "${XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED:-false}"
      PIPELINE_ECS__COMPATIBILITY: "${PIPELINE_ECS__COMPATIBILITY:-disabled}"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    networks:
      - logstash-network
    ports:
      - "9600:9600"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf:ro

volumes:
  kafka-secrets:
    name: "kafka-secrets"
  kafka-data:
    name: "kafka-data"
  kafka-config:
    name: "kafka-config"

networks:
  logstash-network:
    name: "logstash-network"

The Logstash console displays the following lines when filtering by consumer keyword:
docker compose logs -f logstash | grep consumer
logstash  | [2024-12-09T17:11:20,682][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig][main][1cc47ee71c50b28c8d2ef3535bea0308e2047cb3ebc72456a3d39f1ebf27b3e3] ConsumerConfig values: 
logstash  |     client.id = logstash_consumer-0
logstash  |     partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor, class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor]
logstash  | [2024-12-09T17:11:20,839][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer][main][1cc47ee71c50b28c8d2ef3535bea0308e2047cb3ebc72456a3d39f1ebf27b3e3] [Consumer clientId=logstash_consumer-0, groupId=logstash_group] Subscribed to topic(s): logstash-input
logstash  | [2024-12-09T17:11:21,047][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1cc47ee71c50b28c8d2ef3535bea0308e2047cb3ebc72456a3d39f1ebf27b3e3] [Consumer clientId=logstash_consumer-0, groupId=logstash_group] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {logstash-input=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
logstash  | [2024-12-09T17:11:21,049][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata][main][1cc47ee71c50b28c8d2ef3535bea0308e2047cb3ebc72456a3d39f1ebf27b3e3] [Consumer clientId=logstash_consumer-0, groupId=logstash_group] Cluster ID: 5L6g3nShT-eMCtK--X86sw
logstash  | [2024-12-09T17:11:21,169][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata][main][1cc47ee71c50b28c8d2ef3535bea0308e2047cb3ebc72456a3d39f1ebf27b3e3] [Consumer clientId=logstash_consumer-0, groupId=logstash_group] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition logstash-input-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to Ij5j2AoLRNSgijZQRGzMlw
logstash  | [2024-12-09T17:11:21,255][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata][main] [Producer clientId=logstash] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition logstash-output-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to N5hIo5WrTZ2E6Dc0XCVm5Q
logstash  | [2024-12-09T17:20:21,107][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1cc47ee71c50b28c8d2ef3535bea0308e2047cb3ebc72456a3d39f1ebf27b3e3] [Consumer clientId=logstash_consumer-0, groupId=logstash_group] Node -1 disconnected.
logstash  | [2024-12-09T17:20:55,313][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main] [Producer clientId=logstash] Node -1 disconnected.

Similarly, from the Kafka container I get the following lines:
docker compose logs -f kafka | grep consumer
kafka  |        group.consumer.assignors = [org.apache.kafka.coordinator.group.assignor.UniformAssignor, org.apache.kafka.coordinator.group.assignor.RangeAssignor]
kafka  |        group.consumer.heartbeat.interval.ms = 5000
kafka  |        group.consumer.max.heartbeat.interval.ms = 15000
kafka  |        group.consumer.max.session.timeout.ms = 60000
kafka  |        group.consumer.max.size = 2147483647
kafka  |        group.consumer.migration.policy = disabled
kafka  |        group.consumer.min.heartbeat.interval.ms = 5000
kafka  |        group.consumer.min.session.timeout.ms = 45000
kafka  |        group.consumer.session.timeout.ms = 45000
kafka  | [2024-12-09 17:11:21,020] INFO Sent auto-creation request for Set(__consumer_offsets) to the active controller. (kafka.server.DefaultAutoTopicCreationManager)
kafka  | [2024-12-09 17:11:21,167] INFO Sent auto-creation request for Set(__consumer_offsets) to the active controller. (kafka.server.DefaultAutoTopicCreationManager)
kafka  | [2024-12-09 17:11:21,273] INFO Sent auto-creation request for Set(__consumer_offsets) to the active controller. (kafka.server.DefaultAutoTopicCreationManager)
kafka  | [2024-12-09 17:11:21,282] INFO Sent auto-creation request for Set(__consumer_offsets) to the active controller. (kafka.server.DefaultAutoTopicCreationManager)
kafka  | [2024-12-09 17:11:21,365] INFO Sent auto-creation request for Set(__consumer_offsets) to the active controller. (kafka.server.DefaultAutoTopicCreationManager)
kafka  | [2024-12-09 17:11:21,383] INFO Sent auto-creation request for Set(__consumer_offsets) to the active controller. (kafka.server.DefaultAutoTopicCreationManager)

It is possible to test the working http input --> kafka outut path with
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"message": "Hello, Logstash!"}' http://localhost:8080

Similarly, it is possible to check why the path kafka input --> kafka output is not working with:
jq --compact-output -n --arg id "$(uuidgen)" --arg message "Hello" --arg timestamp "$(date)" '$ARGS.named' | docker exec -i kafka /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic logstash-input --bootstrap-server localhost:9092


Update
Ensuring the logstash-input topic exists on Kafka before starting Logstash doesn't fix the issue.
  kafka:
      healthcheck:
        test: "/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic logstash-input --if-not-exists"
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 3

  logstash:
    depends_on:
      kafka:
        condition: service_healthy


Kafka is telling you the logstash-input topic does not exist. Why do you think it should? What is creating it?

I'm creating it via kafka-console-producer.sh

Is there a way to configure consumer reconnection if the topic doesn't exist yet when Logstash tries to connect?

moreover in the logs you can see Subscribed to topic(s): logstash-input
but then there is Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2
